# javascript json array using javascript for getting key/value pair

Tags: javascript, json

Before I start to write my question saying that I had tried with available solutions from stackoverflow but not able to fit my requirement. Please tell me any.

Please check the image in which I have an JSON array format. I want javascript loop in which I want "value" parameter from each options.

Had tried with below code : If I console the statelist then it is showing the result as in below format.

```
options0: {name: "Andaman and Nicobar Islands", value: "1", contact: false}
options1: {name: "Andhra Pradesh", value: "2", contact: false}
options2: {name: "Arunachal Pradesh", value: "3", contact: false}
options3: {name: "Assam", value: "4", contact: false}


for(var i = 1; i <= Object.keys(statelists).length; i++) {
        var obj = statelists.options[i].value;
        console.log(obj);
    }
```

Comment: If you could, please edit  *your actual code* as text into your question - images of code *alone* are [tedious and difficult](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question) to work with and debug. It forces those who would otherwise love to help you to [transcribe your image](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) first, which is a waste of time.

Comment: There's no JSON in your question.

Comment: Please do not post your JSON as image

Comment: @ThumChoonTat As the other comment notes, there is no JSON anywhere in the question or the image.

Comment: @ThumChoonTat posted sample data of javascript array

Comment: There is no array

Answer (score 0):

ANSWER EDITED TO REFLECT COMMENT - As noted in the comments - the content of the question is not JSON - but is an object that contains other objects. You can get an array of the values of each object using `Object.values(statelist)` and then simply iterate over that array with a .forEach loop and console.log() the value of each object.

```js
var statelist = { 
  options0: {name: "Andaman and Nicobar Islands", value: "1", contact: false},
  options1: {name: "Andhra Pradesh", value: "2", contact: false},
  options2: {name: "Arunachal Pradesh", value: "3", contact: false},
  options3: {name: "Assam", value: "4", contact: false}
 }; 
 
 var options = Object.values(statelist); // gives an array of the values of each object
 
 options.forEach(function(option) {
  console.log(option.value); // gives the value of each iteration eg: 1, 2, 3, 4
})
```

Comment: my array is in this format

    var statelist = {
        options0: {name: "Andaman and Nicobar Islands", value: "1", contact: false}
     options1: {name: "Andhra Pradesh", value: "2", contact: false}
     options2: {name: "Arunachal Pradesh", value: "3", contact: false}
     options3: {name: "Assam", value: "4", contact: false}};

Comment: Answer edited to reflect your object based data structure. Same solution - just convert the values into an array using Object.values() and then iterate over it as I did in the first solution.